# MVC HTML Form - some info not passing to controller

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, database

I have a view which is used for entering a large amount of data into a database, the majority of which is of type `List<List<string>>`.

When I submit the form, the data is all there, or at least it shows when analysing the post data in the browser:

[image]

The Questions[][] fields are the `List<List<string>>` data.

But on the controller side, this data doesn't make it through:

[image]

Thus the error I'm getting is a 'NullReferenceException' when it attempts to assign values to the database.

Problem is, I have no idea at which point the form data is failing to pass to the controller.

Even worse is that it was working before, so the error is surely some small typo in my code. I just don't know which specific part I should be looking in.

The Question inputs in the View are like this:

[image]

To compare, the inputs for other data which *does* successfully pass to the controller, are like this:

[image]

so I can't see any major error in the way I'm passing the data across.

The view model looks like this:

[image]

and is passed to the View like this:

[image]

so the data is all initialised properly as far as I can tell.

Where else should I be looking for errors? This whole setup worked fine before, until I changed a couple of things in the View and added a new field to the database.

The database model looks like this:

[image]

I have no idea where else to look.

Any help greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Are you using Ajax?

Comment: Nope, just a standard '@using (Html.BeginForm())' .

Comment: Include your code,  not images of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

I had some values that I didn't want to be completed in the form, so I didn't include them in the View page.

Turns out I needed to include those as @html.HiddenFor() , so that the model can still take a value for everything that it contains.